#  PickerDialog box in wss3.0

Tags: wss-3.0

I need to create a picker dialog box in wss3.0 like the AssetUrlSelector. Can you please tell me how can I use the pickerdialog.master which is present in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS in my custom webpart?

Answer (score 2):

Why re-inventing the wheel when you can use a existing AssetUrlSelector Dialog in your custom Web Part!

Here is an elegant example on how you can use the Asset Picker dialog in your Custom Web part: http://fahadzia.com/blog/2009/11/using-sharepoint-image-picker-to-select-images/

Comment: Hi, I cannot use AssetUrlSelector Dialog because it is not supported in WSS3.0. I cannot find AssetPickers.js in sharepoint root